# Plausibility and possible applications of an antimatter-catalyzed nuclear pulse propulsion system?

Tags: science-fiction, space, space-travel, propulsion

How far are we today from using the technique of using microgram quantities of antimatter (say, antihydrogen) to catalyze a reaction in a sub-critical mass of fissile material for the purpose of interplanetary flight? What theoretical and/or practical roadblocks in the construction and launching of such a vehicle? Additionally, once in flight, what sorts of considerations must be kept in mind? In what ways is this engine most likely to fail during, for example, a trip from low Earth orbit to low Mars orbit?

Comment: One question per post, please. You can ask follow up questions afterward. Keep in mind that the first of your questions — about the current state of the art — belongs on another SE forum because it is not about hypothetical world building.

Comment: The answers below are basically wrong, but I'll happily correct them if you get your question re-opened or reposted ;-)

Comment: Alternative to trying to get your question re-opened here, you could try [space.se], make sure to take their tour and read up in the help center about how to ask a good question. (It's also worth performing a search on the forum for related questions).

Answer (score 0):

Hundreds of years. Existing methods of producing antimatter are horribly inifficient and produce much less than micrograms by several orders of magnitude. One major problem is containment and containment failure will microgram quantities of antihydrogen on board would be catestrophic

Answer (score 0):

Three issues with this: First how would you get it? Second how would you contain it? Third how fast can we ultimately go with a blow-it-up type of rocket fuel?

First it would take a lot of physical effort to *find* antimatter, whether you traveled the universe looking for it or else building some sort of “factory” to manufacture microscopic quantities of it. Chances are very high we will not find any floating around randomly in our solar system. So if our goal is to travel between planets then we’ve already wasted a lot of time traveling between planets looking for the fuel to do just that... If we build a factory to manufacture antimatter fuel, how enormous would that be? Is antimatter created by having a planet sized supercollider? Just building the system to create the fuel would be a massive undertaking and require huge quantities of energy. The antimatter factory would potentially have a lot of mass, at minimum the mass of a large building and at maximum the mass of a hundreds/thousands miles long supercollider. So it would not be feasible to build a spaceship that made it’s own antimatter fuel: The factory would be too heavy to carry onboard the ship.

For the sake of argument let’s say you somehow manage to get some antimatter fuel: then the second point is that it takes a lot of energy to put it in a magnetically repulsive container such that the antimatter would never touch the container walls. How would you build a container to hold it, and how would such a container be powered? You’d need  more fuel to power the contraption that held the antimatter fuel. It’s a bad day in your sci-fi world if the container stops working. So the point here is that if you built a spaceship that used antimatter fuel, you need to bring more energy with you to power the container holding the antimatter. That adds additional mass to the spacecraft, which in turn makes it necessary to bring more antimatter fuel to propel it.

The third issue is the speed of travel. An explosive propulsion system still can’t go faster than light, so the spacecraft would take centuries to get to any interesting local stars. If the goal is simply to travel between planets, it might work, if the mass of the spaceship could be kept to acceptable levels and you have enough time. Consider that a spaceship accelerating at 1G takes about 30 million seconds to reach 99% of light speed. That means it takes about a year to reach 99% light speed, and then another year to decelerate. Voyager I took 3 years 2 months to get to Saturn. An antimatter powered spacecraft would still take a little over two years assuming it accelerated at speeds that wouldn’t kill the passengers.